# Get the number of columns in two SQL tables in a single query?

Tags: sql

I've written two SQL statements:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS table1Count FROM table1 WHERE foo=1;
SELECT Count(*) AS table2Count FROM table2 WHERE bar=2;
```

Both statements return the data I want, but I would like to know how to return a single table with two cells: table1Count and table2Count from a single query.

How do I do construct the query?

Comment: you mean the number of `rows` and a single table with two `columns`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS table1Count FROM table1 WHERE foo=1) AS table1Count, 
       (SELECT Count(*) AS  table2Count FROM table2 WHERE bar=2) AS table2Count;
```

Gives something like:

```
 table1count | table2count 
-------------+-------------
           4 |           6
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Table1' AS "Table", Count(*) As "Count" FROM table1 WHERE foo=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2' AS "Table", Count(*) As "Count" FROM table2 WHERE bar=2;
```

Will produce:

```
Table  | Count
---------------
Table1 | 1
Table2 | 2
```